Intellij Ultimate: "with" code block in python don't recognise the "as" variable type
I use Python 11 with Intellij Ultimate and I have the following code:
async def get_all_user_tabs(user_id: str) -> list[Tab]:
    """Get all the tabs of a user."""
    async with get_db_session() as db_session:
        return await db_session.query(Tab).filter(Tab.user_id == user_id).all()

The get_db_session yields an AsyncIterator[AsyncSession] type:
@asynccontextmanager
async def get_db_session() -> AsyncIterator[AsyncSession]:
    """Get the database session."""
    try:
        async with _ASYNC_LOCAL_SESSION_MAKER() as session:
            yield session
    except SQLAlchemyError as e:
        _LOGGER.exception(e)
        raise

but the db_session is still of type Any:
get_db_session return type shown here
db_session type shown here
